# How do you solve this mineflayer problem?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i've been trying to make a code for a bot in minecraft but when doing the command:

```
node index.js
```

Then this happens:

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\monst\Downloads\Serverchat\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

this is the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const client = new Discord.Client();

let prefix = ".";
let bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    version: "1.12.2",
    host: "example.org",
    username: "email",
    password: "password",
})

client.on("ready", async => {
    console.log("Bot Online")
})

bot.on("login", async => {
    console.log("Ingame Bot Online")
    bot.chat("Online!")
})

bot.on("message", message => {
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(742454971450261557)
    if (!channel) return; 
    channel.send(`${message}`)
})

client.login("token")
```

if anyone could help, that would mean the world to me!

Comment: A) What is this file called? B) How are you running it?

Comment: It's also worth noting that numbers like `742454971450261557` are too big to be represented normally and will likely get rounded down. You need to use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) as in `742454971450261557n`.

Comment: @tadman this file is called index.js.

Comment: @tadman oh and those big numbers are used as a id for a discord channel. if its not used and if i place a n at the end, it doesnt work.

Comment: @TobiasNielsen Discord.js expects you to provide IDs as strings, not as numbers, for precisely the reason tadman explained above.

Comment: @Klaycon i have tried to change it now and it still doesnt work and sends the same error message. this is weird.

Comment: @TobiasNielsen read my answer. The error message is Node literally just not finding the file you're trying to point it at, because it doesn't exist in the directory you ran the command. Not a single thing you change in code will fix that.

Comment: @tadman also running it on visual code studio

Comment: It's worth checking that you can run a very simple `console.log("Hello, world!");` script first.

Comment: @tadman huh, it cant. gets the same error. weird.

Comment: @Klaycon then how do you change it so it does? sorry, im new to node and coding lol.

Comment: @TobiasNielsen **What folder** is your main script file located in? Your `index.js` with all the code you pasted in the question? You **need to point node.js at this folder**. You said you're running it through Visual Studio Code, are you running it using a run action (so that you can hit Debug or F5 or something to run it) or are you typing `node index.js` into the VSC terminal?

Comment: @Klaycon my main script file is located in a folder called Serverchat under Workspace. And, i am using node index.js and typing that into the VSC terminal.

Comment: @TobiasNielsen VSC is searching in your downloads folder. Are you certain that's the right place? Are you *certain* the file is named `index.js` and not something else?

Comment: @Klaycon it is named index.js. sorry i fell asleep like 8 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

## Reset your token!

Your bot's token is like a username and password in one. Anyone who obtains it can **take any action whatsoever as if they were your bot**, including talk through it and delete channels and stuff like that. I redacted it from your question via edit but I strongly urge you to go to the Discord portal and reset it now.

---

That aside, the primary issue:

The error is clearly written. `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\monst\Downloads\Serverchat\index.js'`. This means you have no file in that folder named `index.js`. Seeing it's a discord bot as well, perhaps you meant `node bot.js` instead? If not, your code may be in another working directory. Change your working directory in your command prompt using `cd` to where you've located your bot's code and `node_modules`.

---

One other thing: JavaScript cannot represent Snowflakes as raw numbers - precision loss will cause the last few numbers to change slightly. For this reason, discord libraries (including discord.js) require you to pass IDs as strings, like this:

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.get("742454971450261557")
```